# Analytical solution to $a^x+b^x=x$

Tags: roots, exponential-function

Maybe stupid question, but I am wondering. Is there an analytical solution to equation 
$$a^x+b^x=x$$
for general $a$, $b$. How should I tackle this problem, if I want to find at least one $x$.
Thanks.

Comment: Give one example of your choice and I shall work it.

Comment: This is not at all a stupid question ! You raised a very interesting problem ! Thank you.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I actually have no specific $a$ and $b$. They are just some parameters. All I know that they are positive, so $a>0$, $b>0$.

Comment: I shall work some examples tomorrow and post some results here.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. Looking forward.

Comment: Questions like this drive mathematics forward!

Comment: @pisoir. I enjoy this problem ! Would you mind if I define (for my work) a new mathematical function named Pisoir[a,b] which would return the closest x to the solution of a^x + b^x - x = 0 ? I am serious.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici :)Sure, you can name it like that (although it's just a nickname). Btw. if this ends up in some interesting paper, I will be very glad to read it. So please, keep me posted.

Comment: @pisoir. It does not matter it is a nickname. For sure, I shall keep you informed. This problem is very interesting (at least to me !) as a generalization of Lambert function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici When I first came to this problem I thought it must be already solved in some way using Lambert functions. It seems I was wrong. Of course there may be bigger generalizations like find solutions to $\sum_i a_i b_i^x = cx+d$, but that's completely new problem.

Comment: Analytic solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4290304/is-there-a-way-to-analytically-solve-x-alpha-y-alpha-alphax-y-for/4600641#4600641)

Answer (score 6):

For $a \ge e^{1/e} = 1.444667861\ldots$, we have $a^x \ge x$ for all $x$. So we require at least $a < e^{1/e}$ and $b < e^{1/e}$.

And for $a > e^{1/2e} = 1.201943368\ldots$, we have $a^x > x/2$ for all $x$. So we require at least $a \le e^{1/2e}$ or $b \le e^{1/2e}$.

You can check these figures by differentiating $f(x) = a^x - x$ (resp. $f(x) = a^x - x/2$) with respect to $x$, setting this derivative to zero to find the value of $x$ that minimises $f(x)$, and choosing $a$ so that this minimum value is zero.

Comment: i saw you edited. ok +1.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit too.

Comment: @TonyK I see your point and I agree that it holds separately. For $a^x$ and $b^x$. But I think that even when $a>e^{1/e}$ there could be some $b^x$ such that the equation $a^x+b^x=x$ would still hold.

Comment: @DonAnselmo: Only if you allow $b < 0$, which makes the problem ill-defined.

Answer (score 3):

As an illustration example of this problem, I propose here the basis of a possible algorithm; this will use a second order Newton iteration method and, as usual, the key point will be to find a reasonable starting point.

Assuming that Lambert function is available, let me consider two functions $$f(x) =a^x+b^x-x$$ and $$g(x)=2c^x-x$$ 
Expanding both functions as Taylor series built at x = 0, parameter "c" is Sqrt[a b] and the solution of g(x)=0 is given by -W(-2z)/z where z=Log(c). From here Newton iterations can start.

Suppose a=0.75 and b=1.25; this leads to c=0.968246 and an estimate equal to 1.88214 for g(x)=0. The successive iterates are 2.14996, 2.15557, 2.15558, 2.15558.

If Lambert function is not available, the first order Taylor expansion of f(x) gives an estimate equal to 2 / (1 - Log(a b)) which, for the selected case, is 1.87875 and the solution path will be identical to the previous one.

The last method clearly shows that there would be a problem if a b = e as already underlined in the comments and answers to the post.

If fact, except if a plot of the function is done, we do not know if solutions exist. So, in the case of any doubt, my suggestion would be to minimize f(x)^2 with respect to x

Comment: Wonderful comment. Maybe a question can be raised. Can we say something about NUMBER of solutions? Newton iterations will converge to some solution, but can we say if it's the only root (solution to the equation)?

Comment: It is too early to conclude but, since this is YOUR function, I should tell that I do not expect more than one solution. May be no solution at all; this is why I am also considering minimization. Whatever a and b could be, for x=0, f=2 and f''>0. Let us share ideas on that problem. Get the ideas and I shall be the slave !!!!

Comment: Thanks for giving me credits,but I don't believe there is something like "my function". I happy you found this problem interesting and I will be happy if I could read something more about it from you in the future.
From all my simulations, and also as you mentioned,I also believe that this equation has always at most one solution (for given a, b). But I have no proof or any real ideas what to do more than what you already mentioned with the minimization technique. I will try to keep this question updated as soon as I find something new and interesting about it.Thank you for your great inputs.

Comment: @pisoir. I do not know how old you are (you know my age). One of the most "difficult" thing is to give a name to something new. Since I am lazy, your nickname is good for me. To continue this discussion, is there any way to be in direct contact (phone, e-mail,...). You have my e-mail address in my profile. Cheers.

Comment: @pisoir. I cannot see you e-mail address either. Mine if cfl-consultant at club-internet.fr

Answer (score 2):

There is no closed-form solution in terms of standard functions, except in special cases.
If $a$ and $b$ are given, you might try numerical methods, such as Newton's.

Answer (score 2):

Notice if $a=b=1$, then you get trivial solution $x = 2$. I claim that if $a,b$ are both $\geq2$, then there is NO solution!. To see this, Suppose there is a solution $x$ such that

$$ a^x + b^x = x $$.

Notice since $a$ and $b$ are greater than $2$, then the following is trivially true

$a^x > x $ and $b^x > x $. This implies that $a^x + b^x > 2x $

$$ x = a^x + b^x > 2x \implies x < 0 $$.

However, $a^x, b^x$ are always positive for every $x$, hence $a^x + b^x$ must be positive. Contradiction.

Comment: @DonAnselmo. I totally agree with your statements. Do you think that more than one solution could exist ? Thanks and cheers.

Comment: @DonAnselmo I suggest to write that when $a > 2$ or $b > 2$, then we don't have solutions, and hence there can be solutions when both $a$ and $b$ are less than $2$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, here's another solution: $a=b=-2$ and $x=-1$ :)

Comment: Also $a=b=\frac{1}{16}$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Your claim that there are solutions if $a < 2$ or $b < 2$ is completely unfounded $-$ in fact, it's obviously false.

Comment: @GintasK. I think we must forget the case a=b since, for such a case, the solution is given by Lambert function : x = -W[-2 Log(a)] / Log(a).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Actually, that's my current status. To somehow incorporate Lambert function, but I have no luck with it (maybe it's totally misleading way).

Comment: @pisoir. There is no hope of finding an analytical solution. Newton method will be one of the possible solution. The interesting point is to find a "good" starting point. Cheers.

Comment: $(a,b,x)= (\frac 12, \frac 12,1)$ and in general for $x=1$, it simply suffices to have $b=1-a$

Comment: @GottfriedHelms. Good remark for x=1 ! Cheers.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Or the other way. If $b=1-a$, we know that $x=1$ is a solution to the equation. Good remark indeed.

Comment: @pisoir. I think it is the opposite : if x=1, then b=1-a.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I said it inprecisely. I wanted to say, that if $b=1-a$ then $x=1$ is one of the solutions. (I guess it might not be the only one).

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting special case is if $b=\frac{1}{a}\ne 1$, i.e., equation changes to $a^x+a^{-x}=x$.

We can then find that if $a=a^\star=e^{\frac{1}{2\sinh q}}=1.392877\dots$, or $a=a^{\star\star}=e^{-\frac{1}{2\sinh q}}=0.7179\dots$ where $q$ is solution to $\coth q = q$ (this can be found in literature to be $q=1.19967874\dots$) then there is exactly one solution ($x=2\cosh q\approx3.6203\dots$).

If $a>a^\star$ or $a<a^{\star\star}$ then there is no solution, and if $a\in(a^{\star\star},a^\star)=(0.7179,1.392877)$ there are exactly two solutions (both for $x>0$).

Comment: Analysis of this case can be found in http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6600v2