# Is there a way to analytically solve $x^\alpha + y^\alpha = \alpha(x + y)$ for $\alpha$, other than $\alpha = 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, special-functions, closed-form

Suppose $x, y > 0$ are fixed arbitrary positive numbers. Is there a way to solve $x^\alpha + y^\alpha = \alpha(x + y)$ for $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$ analytically, excluding the trivial solution $\alpha = 1$?

This question cropped up during some research into generalising the inversion in the sphere map to Bregman distances. I have a plausible generalisation, and I'm trying to apply it to a nice Bregman sphere, but out popped this particular equation.

I do understand that such a solution will not involve elementary functions. I have no real skillset with special functions, so all I could do was try solving it with a CAS. I don't have Maple or Mathematica on my computer, but I tried using Wolfram Alpha and SageMath. The latter was useless, returning $\alpha = \frac{x^\alpha + y^\alpha}{x + y}$.

The former gave me nothing, simply telling me that computation time was exceeded. Indeed, even when I substituted a particular value for $y$, Wolfram Alpha still gave me no results. Only once I substituted two particular values for $x$ and $y$ would it give me an approximation with no closed form.

I realise that there's little hope for a nice solution, but I thought I'd check here before I give up completely.

Comment: Is it obvious that such an $\alpha\neq 1$ exists for any $x,y>0$?

Comment: If $f(x,\alpha)=x^{\alpha}-\alpha x,$ you want $f(x,\alpha)+f(y,\alpha)=0.$ Not sure how that helps.

Comment: @Surb Not immediately, no. My wider geometric intuition about the problem (which I'm reluctant to spell out here) suggests that there should be exactly one solution (other than $\alpha = 1$).

Comment: @TheoBendit Are you looking for "a closed form" like solution? E.g. Hypergeometric functions or approximation methods?

Comment: $$\partial f/\partial \alpha=(\log x)x^{\alpha}-x,$$ so you get one extremum at $\alpha_0 =1-\log\log x/\log x.$ So if $x<1$ there is no extremum. If $1<x<e$ then the extremum is $>1,$ and if $x>e$ the extremum is in $(0,1).$

Comment: @Surb Actually, let me amend that slightly. My geometric intuition tells me that there will be a unique solution *unless* $x$ and $y$ satisfy $x^x y^y = e^{x + y}$, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @lonestudent I am hoping for a closed form, yes. I want to be able to study this function $\alpha$ of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: $f(x,\alpha)$ as Thomas defined it is convex as a function of $\alpha$, $0$ at $\alpha = 1$.  If $x > 1$, $f(x,\alpha) < 0$ for $\alpha$ in some interval $(1,\alpha^*(x))$ with $\alpha^*(x) > 1$; if $0 < x < 1$, $f(x,\alpha) < 0$ for all $\alpha > 1$ and $> 0$ for $0 < \alpha < 1$.  So there should be no solution other than $\alpha = 1$ if $0 < x,y < 1$, there will definitely be one if $x, y > 1$.  I;m not sure about the case where $0 < x < 1 < y$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Although I cann't understand advanced special functions, closed form solutions are always more stunnig to me. But our case seems hopeless. Because I think there is only one option to solve the special case equation $2^{\alpha}+3^{\alpha}=5\alpha $ in closed form: Lambert-W function. But the Lambert function cannot solve this equation. Note that, Lambert solution cannot escape WA's advanced algorithm. Only if $x=y$ then the Lambert-W will perfectly work.

Comment: I was about to add more context to my question, but I spotted an error in my working. The problem as stated is still sensible, so I'll leave it up, but the real equation I want to solve is $x^\alpha + y^\alpha = \alpha(x + y + 2)$. This is the problem to which my geometric intuition pertains, not the one stated in the question. Apologies to @surb in particular, and thank you to everyone who has been thinking about the problem.

Comment: Also: if $y=1$ then Lambert W can solve for $a$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Fortunately $\alpha(x+y+2)$ can be dealt with in the same way as $\alpha(x+y)$, and I think it can be generalised to problems like $x^\alpha+y^\alpha+r=\alpha(x^\beta+y^\beta+s)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whilst it is very likely a closed form does not exist (see for instance [Two exponential terms equation solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511558/two-exponential-terms-equation-solution?noredirect=1)), it is possible to determine a series expansion for $\alpha$.

Let $z=f(\alpha)$ where $f(\alpha)=x^\alpha+y^\alpha-\alpha(x+y)$. Since $f$ is analytic at zero with a non-zero derivative there, we can use the Lagrange inversion theorem to obtain an expansion about zero:$$\alpha=\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n\frac{(z-f(0))^n}{n!}\bigg\vert_{z=0}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-2)^ng_n}{n!}$$ where \begin{align}g_n=\lim_{\alpha\to0}D_\alpha^{n-1}\left(\frac\alpha{x^\alpha+y^\alpha-\alpha(x+y)-2}\right)^n.\end{align} It is important to note that this only works when $\alpha<1$; that is, the series is valid only if $$y>e^{W(-x(\log x-1)/e)+1},$$ which follows by solving the tangent case $f'(\alpha)=0$ where $1$ is the only root. In addition, the domain of $W$ over the reals is $[-1/e,\infty)$, so when $x>e^{W(1/e)+1}\approx3.6$, there is no restriction on the value of $y$.

In relation to the coefficients, the first term can be evaluated using L'Hopital
\begin{align}g_1&=\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac\alpha{x^\alpha+y^\alpha-\alpha(x+y)-2}\\&=\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac1{x^\alpha\log x+y^\alpha\log y-(x+y)}\\&=\frac1{\log x+\log y-(x+y)}\end{align} and the second term requires repeated application \begin{align}g_2&=\lim_{\alpha\to0}D_\alpha\left(\frac\alpha{x^\alpha+y^\alpha-\alpha(x+y)-2}\right)^2\\&=\small\lim_{\alpha\to0}2\left(\frac\alpha{x^\alpha+y^\alpha-\alpha(x+y)-2}\right)\left(\frac{x^\alpha+y^\alpha-\alpha(x+y)-2-\alpha(x^\alpha\log x+y^\alpha\log y-(x+y))}{(x^\alpha+y^\alpha-\alpha(x+y)-2)^2}\right)\\&=\small\frac2{\log x+\log y-(x+y)}\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac{x^\alpha+y^\alpha-\alpha(x+y)-2-\alpha(x^\alpha\log x+y^\alpha\log y-(x+y))}{(x^\alpha+y^\alpha-\alpha(x+y)-2)^2}\\&=\small\frac2{\log x+\log y-(x+y)}\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac{-\alpha(x^\alpha\log^2x+y^\alpha\log^2y)}{2(x^\alpha+y^\alpha-\alpha(x+y)-2)(x^\alpha\log x+y^\alpha\log y-(x+y))}\\&=\small\frac{-1}{\log x+\log y-(x+y)}\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac\alpha{x^\alpha+y^\alpha-\alpha(x+y)-2}\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac{x^\alpha\log^2x+y^\alpha\log^2y}{x^\alpha\log x+y^\alpha\log y-(x+y)}\\&=-\frac{\log^2x+\log^2y}{(\log x+\log y-(x+y))^3},\end{align} and so on. When $x$ is large (the value of $y$ does not matter), these first two terms $$\alpha\approx-\frac2{\log x+\log y-(x+y)}-\frac{2(\log^2x+\log^2y)}{(\log x+\log y-(x+y))^3}$$ already give a very good approximation of the true value of $\alpha$. [Here is a visualisation.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/axywbwxsog)

Comment: $(+1)!$ A question in my mind is: How to make an exact proof that this equation cannot be solved by special or elementary functions?  What I mean is actually this: For example, $x^5-x+1=0$ cannot be solved by finite term of radicals.  We have an exact proof.  Is such an exact proof possible?  What theory do we need for this?I'm actually very curious..

Comment: @lonestudent See https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589148

Comment: Great answer. How did you obtain the range of convergence? It is not clear to me that the series could never calculate an $\alpha\gt1$, or that $y$ must be greater than the W function expression.

Comment: @FShrike The reason we have $\alpha<1$ is that I have chosen the series to be expanded about zero. Since there are two roots ($\alpha$ and $1$) and $z=0$, the series (which is unique) will only capture the root closest to zero (ie $\min\{\alpha,1\}$). Therefore, to obtain the value when $\alpha>1$ we will need to expand at a value $\beta$ such that $|\beta-\alpha|<|\beta-1|$. The inequality involving $x$ and $y$ is a direct consequence of the inequality $\alpha<1$ which I will elaborate now.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 1):

A general analytic solution in prescribed classes of functions is possibly not known. But of course that cannot be proven.

$$x^\alpha+y^\alpha=\alpha(x+y)$$

$$e^{\ln(x)\alpha}+e^{\ln(y)\alpha}-\alpha x-\alpha y=0$$

Applying Ritt's theorem on elementary inverses of elementary functions (Ritt 1925) and Schanuel's conjecture yields that the elementary functions $\alpha\to e^{\ln(x)\alpha}+e^{\ln(y)\alpha}-\alpha x-\alpha y$ over non-discrete domains cannot have elementary partial inverses. Therefore the equation cannot be solved by simply rearranging it by applying only finite numbers of elementary functions (elementary operations) readable from the equation. It is not known if all solutions of the equation are elementary numbers (Lin 1983, Chow 1999).

I give some cases where analytic solutions exist.

If $\alpha$ is rational, we get an algebraic equation.

If $x=1$, $y=1$, $x=y$ or $x=\alpha^{\frac{1}{\alpha-1}}$, $\alpha$ can be represented in terms of Lambert W.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explicit solution using [Lagrange reversion](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=x3xpVB657gE) and more familiar notation:

$$a^x+b^x=cx\implies x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left.\frac{d^{n-1}(a^x+b^x)^n}{dx^{n-1}}\right|_{x=0}}{c^nn!}$$

Using the binomial theorem:

$$a^x+b^x=cx\implies x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{\ln^{n-1}\left(a^kb^{n-k}\right)}{c^n n!}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{((n-k)\ln(b)+k\ln(a))^{n-1}}{k!(n-k)!c^n}$$

Where $0\le k\le d\ge n$ [**shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3%5Ew%2B4%5Ew-%283%2B4%2B2%29w%2Cw%3D%28sum%5B1%2F%28%283%2B4%2B2%29%5En+n%21%29+%28sum%5Bbinomial%28n%2C+k%29+log%283%5Ek+4%5E%28-k+%2B+n%29%29%5E%28n-1%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C200%7D%5D%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C200%7D%5D%29). Unfortunately, the convergence is pretty slow. Fortunately, the only inner sum [pattern](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28%28n-k%29+b%2Bk+a%29%5E8+binom%28n%2Ck%29%2F%28c%5En+n%21%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cn%7D%5D) I could find by switching the sums, or not, was with the [hypergeometric function $_p\text F_q$](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/03/01/06/):

$$\boxed{e^{ax}+e^{bx}=cx\implies x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(bn)^{n-1}}{c^nn!}\,_n\text F_{n-1}\left(-n,\frac{bn}{a-b}+1,\dots, \frac{bn}{a-b}+1;\frac{bn}{a-b},\dots,\frac{bn}{a-b};-1\right)}$$

The hypergeometric function reduces to a polynomial for which we are searching for a form in terms of simpler functions.

Comment: Maybe the binomial theorem and [$B_n(x)$ Bell polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html) give another form for the series solution?